# Is there a recommended way of writing the contents of variables to a text file?

Tags: c#, .net-core, mono

As a tutorial project I had to create a Coffee Machine Simulator using c#. I have completed this project successfully, but I would like the contents of the variables to be written to a file so that the user does not need to set it up again. I have tried this by attempting the demo project from Microsoft:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection.Metadata;
using System.Text;

namespace TestingCode
{
    class Program
    {
        
        public static void Main()
        {
            string path = "Test.txt";
            
            try
            {
                // Create the file, or overwrite if the file exists.
                using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter a string:");
                    string input = Console.ReadLine();
                    byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(input);
                    // Add some information to the file.
                    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
                }

                // Open the stream and read it back.
                using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
                {
                    string s = "";
                    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(s);
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This code successfully runs and writes the value of the user input to a text file. Please can anybody help me write the variables into a text file and read from them as well.

Thanks,
KINGAWESOME266

Comment: `input` is also variable and you are writing its value. You can also use `File.Write` and `File.Read`

Comment: What exactly u mean by writing variables to a file? In case your are looking for persisting the state of an object then u should look at json or xml serialisation.

Comment: **[Using Application Settings and User Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings)**

Answer (score 1):

Edit: you can install Newtonsoft.Json by using nugget package manager

The fastest and easiest way I can think of is using Newtonsoft.Json to serialize data

Create a class to store your variables:
Let's say we have this Model class which stores our variables

```cs
public class Model
{
        public int Variable1;
        public string Variable2;
        public List<string> Variable3;
}
```

Here is our object that we want to serialize:

```
Model m = new Model()
{
    Variable1 = 1,
    Variable2 = "test test",
    Variable3 = new List<string>() { "list element 1 ", "list element 2", "list element 3"}
};
```

To serialize this object call JsonConvert.SerializeObject with your object as param
The output of this is a json string, in our case:

{"Variable1":1,"Variable2":"test test","Variable3":["list element 1 ","list element 2","list element 3"]}

```
var serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(m);
```

Save the string to a file and read it back again

```cs
File.WriteAllText("serialized.txt", serializedData);
var loadedData = File.ReadAllText("serialized.txt");
```

Convert back the read string to an object by calling JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(yourObject);

```cs
var loadedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(loadedData);
```

[image]

Complete example:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Model m = new Model()
    {
        Variable1 = 1,
        Variable2 = "test test",
        Variable3 = new List<string>() { "list element 1 ", "list element 2", "list element 3" }
    };

    var serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(m);

    File.WriteAllText("serialized.txt", serializedData);

    var loadedData = File.ReadAllText("serialized.txt");
    var loadedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(loadedData);
}
```